# Forcing non-root process to wait for root in mpi4py

Tags: python-3.x, mpi, python-multiprocessing, mpi4py

I have code that is doing some interactive plotting.

- Root process is doing the actual plotting
- Computation is spread across all processes

After the plot is initially produced, the root process then waits for the user to interact with the plot at which point the parameters will change and the data needs to be computed again.

The problem I have is that I have an infinite loop on the root process to wait for the user's input, but in the meantime the other processes are reaching the end of the program and exiting, even though they will be required again.

So how do I get the non-root processes to wait for a signal from root and at that point to jump back into execution?

Psuedocode

```
from mpi4py import MPI
def computation_function(self):
    self.initialise_arrays()
    self.parallel_compute()
    MPI.COMM_WORLD.Gather(destination,source,root=0)

def on_click(self,event):
    """Only called on root"""
    self.parse_event()
    self.update_parameters()
    # This function needs to somehow get called on all processes
    self.computation_function()

def wait_for_user(self):
    
    while True:
        if rank == 0:
            # self.fig only defined on root
            # event_loop will call on_click()
            self.fig.canvas.start_event_loop()
        else:
            # need a function here which causes the non-root processes to wait
            MPI.some_function()
```

Comment: Typically, rank 0 waits for user input, and then message the other ranks.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the key point I guess. Which function should I use to tell the other processes to wait for a message? I am finding the documentation confusing

Comment: `MPI_Recv()` is a good start! or you can use a collective such as `MPI_Bcast()` or `MPI_Scatter()`